# Strange MAC addresses in wireless sniffing

Tags: mac-address, sniffing, wifi

Doing wireless sniffing, I can see that my AP sends large data frames to unexisting MAC addresses like (in hex): 
33330000000c, 3333000000fb, 3333ffaf8b6c (all start with 3333)
01005e0000fb, 01005e7ffffa, 01005e000001 (all start with 01005e)

I have managed to find that 33:33:00:00:00:00 is IPv6 multicast address. Can anybody explain the address starting with 01005e?

UPDATE: Some of the group MAC addresses one can find here:
http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/grpmac/public.html

Answer (score 2):

As you already found out, MAC addresses beginning with 33:33 are IPv6 multicast - MAC addresses beginning with 01:00:5e are [IPv4 multicast](http://www.iana.org/go/rfc7042)